# PHP DateInterval inconsistent days count

Tags: php, datetime, dateinterval

Take the following PHP code:

```
<?php
$timezone = new DateTimeZone('UTC');
$startDate = new DateTime('2022-09-26T00:00:00', $timezone);
$endDate1 = new DateTime('2023-02-28T00:00:00', $timezone);
$endDate2 = new DateTime('2023-03-01T00:00:00', $timezone);
$interval1 = $endDate1->diff($startDate);
$interval2 = $endDate2->diff($startDate);
print_r($interval1);
print_r($interval2);
```

And here's the output:

```
DateInterval Object
(
    [y] => 0
    [m] => 5
    [d] => 2
    [h] => 0
    [i] => 0
    [s] => 0
    [f] => 0
    [weekday] => 0
    [weekday_behavior] => 0
    [first_last_day_of] => 0
    [invert] => 1
    [days] => 155
    [special_type] => 0
    [special_amount] => 0
    [have_weekday_relative] => 0
    [have_special_relative] => 0
)
DateInterval Object
(
    [y] => 0
    [m] => 5
    [d] => 5
    [h] => 0
    [i] => 0
    [s] => 0
    [f] => 0
    [weekday] => 0
    [weekday_behavior] => 0
    [first_last_day_of] => 0
    [invert] => 1
    [days] => 156
    [special_type] => 0
    [special_amount] => 0
    [have_weekday_relative] => 0
    [have_special_relative] => 0
)
```

Can someone please explain why first interval's `y-m-d` is **0-5-2** when `days` count is 155, but second interval's `y-m-d` is **0-5-5** even if only 1 day was added (infact the `days` count is 156)?

I tried to port the same code in other languages (JavaScript and python to be precise) and the result for the first interval is the same as PHP's one: 5 months and 2 days.
However the result for the second interval is 5 months and 3 days (as i would expect) and not 5 months and 5 days as PHP says.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP finds the difference between two dates by naively computing the difference between all components of a timestamp. (years, months, days, etc. ([ref](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/date/lib/interval.c#L146))) So the second interval would look like `(y=1, m=-6, d=-25)` at this stage. However, this makes little sense to us humans, so PHP tries to normalize this interval by adjusting each field if the next one down would over- or underflow. ([ref](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/date/lib/tm2unixtime.c#L188)). But months do not contain a consistent amount of days, so PHP tries to be smart and does day-to-month adjustments based on the length of the month we started in. ([ref](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/date/lib/tm2unixtime.c#L70))

So if the first date is in February, the days field will be adjusted by 28 days: `(y=1, m=-7, d=2)`, while March has 31 days, yielding `(y=1, m=-7, d=5)`. The next step for both intervals is the month adjustment, which is identical. A year has twelve months, so we get `(y=0, m=5, d=2)` and `(y=0, m=5, d=5)`.

---

Knowing this, we can have some more fun with PHP being weird

```php
$start = new DateTime('2022-09-26');
$end = new DateTime('2023-03-01');

$start->diff($end); // +5m 3d
$end->diff($start); // -5m 5d
```

---

**EDIT**: My first assumption on how PHP worked internally turned out to be incorrect, so the answer above has been rewritten after @KIKO Software posed their question.

Comment: How does PHP determine how many months fit between 2 dates? Doesn't this take the 5 days that are subtracted from this interval into account?

Comment: So if i get it correctly using my example: `$start->diff($end)` starts at 2022-09-26, counts 1 month for every 26th of the month it hits till 2023-02-26 (5 months) and adds the remaining days 02-27, 02-28, 03-01 (3 days). So 5 months 3 days. Which is the default behavior of other languages (like JS `end.diff(start)` or Python `end - start`).
While `$end->diff($start)` does the opposite. Starts at 2023-03-01 and goes backwards, counts 1 month for every 1st of the month it hits till 2022-10-01 (5 months) and adds the remaining days 09-30, 09-29, 09-28, 09-27, 09-26 (5 days). So 5 months 5 days.

Comment: @Fabius: I think that's a much better explanation than was given in this answer.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware, my first answer didn't reflect how PHP handles this internally, so I've updated my answer and included sources. To answer your specific question, PHP determines this by taking the difference between the months field of the two dates and adjusting that to be in a reasonable range (larger than -1, smaller than 13)

Comment: @Fabius, that's indeed how I intended my answer, but after digging into the source code, it turns out to be incorrect. I've updated my answer to reflect how PHP actually does this. If it is still unclear, do let me know and I'll try to clarify

Comment: @CerebralFart: Thanks for your updated and detailed answer. Btw your original answer (which i tried to better clarify, also to myself, in my comment) was not really _incorrect_. It was just the resulting effect of PHP approach to calculating date intervals, which I think comes handy to know and its not really documented in the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)

Comment: I appreciate your effort to improve this answer, but it is still quite difficult to understand. Yes, when looking at the source code everything becomes clear, but how many people will look at, or even understand, those? The answer itself, without the references, should be comprehensible. However, I have to admit that I would have a hard time explaining this clearly as well. A bit of careful formatting, and a clear example, can probably help a lot?